# Dynamic Menu is not loading properly in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi i am trying to load menu dynamically in Layout page.

Eg

```
 1)AccountsMasters

 1.1)AccountsCategory

 1.2)Accounts
```

Here I load the submenus that is accounts category,accounts dynamically but i can't able to load Accounts Master main menu dynamically.I tried to load the main menu same as like submenu but its loading  2 times that is 
 eg

```
1)AccountsMasters

 1.1)AccountsCategory

1)AccountsMasters

 1.2)Accounts
```

its load the  main menu two times

My Table

UID           MainMenuName         SubMenuName            MAINMENIID

1           ACCOUNTSMASTER         ACCOUNTS                 1

2           ACCOUNTMASTER          ACCOUNTSCATEGORY         1

3           PRODUCTMASTER          PRODUCTS                  2

4           PRODUCTMASTER           PRODUCTCATEGORY          2

**My model SubMenuViewModel**

```
public class SubMenuviewmodel
{
    public string SubMenu { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string MainMenuName { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }

}
```

**Menu Model**

```
  public class Menu
{
    public Menu()
    {
        MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
        SubMenuItems = new List<SubMenuviewmodel>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
    public List<SubMenuviewmodel> SubMenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
  public ActionResult SubMenu()
    {
        var menu = new Menu();

        var submenu = db.SubAplicationNames.Select(e => new
        {
            submenuuid = e.SubAplicationNameID,
            submenuname = e.SubMenuName,
            submenuparentidd = e.SubAplicationNameID,
            mainmenuname=e.ApplicationName

        }).ToList();

        var submenulist = new List<SubMenuviewmodel>();
        for (var item = 0; item < submenu.Count();item++ )
        {
            var submenuitemslist = new SubMenuviewmodel { SubMenu = submenu[item].submenuname.ToString(),MainMenuName=submenu[item].mainmenuname
                ,ControllerName="",ActionName="" };
            submenulist.Add(submenuitemslist);
        }
        menu.SubMenuItems = submenulist;
            return View(menu);
    }
```

**My View Code**

```
  @model DynamicMenuLoading.Models.Menu
  @{
     Layout = null;
   }
  <ul>
    <li>
    @foreach(var item in Model.SubMenuItems)
    { 
    <a href="#">
        <span>@item.MainMenuName</span>
    </a>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="@Url.Action(item.ActionName , item.ControllerName )"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>@item.SubMenu</a></li>

     </ul>
      }
      </li>
    </ul>
```

This code gives the result which is mention above.it giving wrong output. Any one tell me what mistake i did. I tried my level best to explain the issue.Any one understand my issue and help me to resolve this problem.

Advance Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

how about if you try something like this

```
 @model DynamicMenuLoading.Models.Menu
  @{
     Layout = null;
   }
  <ul>
    <li>
  @{
    string name = "";

    foreach (var item in Model.SubMenuItems)
    {
        if (item.MainMenuName != name)
        {
            name = item.MainMenuName;
            <a href="#">
                <span>@item.MainMenuName</span>
            </a>
        }


      <ul>
      <li><a href="@Url.Action(item.ActionName , item.ControllerName )"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>@item.SubMenu</a></li>

     </ul>

     }
    }
     </li>
  </ul>
```